# VBA outlook - send email and categorize the CC email

Tags: vba, email, outlook, categories

I have been using public folder and sending emails on outlook. Whenever we send emails with the public folder email address (e.g info@company.com), we will CC info@company.com. So that we will keep the email in our public folder.

I have created some VBA code to send outlook email automatically.
My question is: Is it possible to automatically categorize (e.g. customer-inquiry) the email in our public folder when I send the email without showing the category to recipient (as .

```
Sub outlookActivate1()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


    With OutMail

        .BCC = ""
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

        .Categories = "customer-inquiry"
        .ShowCategoriesDialog
        .Save
        .display

End With

On Error GoTo 0


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set oItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I would save the sent item to the onto-mailbox instead of cc the mail there.  That gives you more options to work with the item.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. You may consider adding a user property to the mail item instead. See [UserProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862196(v=office.15).aspx) for more information.